# div background image only shows with hardcoded values

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to set an image by creating a div with a background-image. This code works, but I don't like that it has hardcoded values for height and width. The percentage values just don't work and the image disappears. Is it possible to avoid putting the actual pixel height and width in case I want to change the image in the future and not have to put in new values?

```
//html

<div class='img'></div>


//css
.img {
    background-image: url('../images/istockphoto-1353553203-1024x1024.jpg');
    display:block;
    background-size: cover;

    width: 1200px;
    height: 1000px;

}
```

Comment: you may instead use a combination of `min-height` and `max-height`. Anyway, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Try using the "Inspect" function in your browser. You can change CSS definitions dynamically and see how that changes the appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define the `min-height` and `max-height` of the image. The percentage doesn't work for you because it cannot fill any parent element. Try to make the div bigger and add any parent to it. You can view your page in different screen sizes with your browser's "Inspect" function.